# How to correct the division result in this MySQL query?

Tags: mysql, database, replace, mysql-workbench, integer-division

I have this table:

```
CREATE TABLE `mytable` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `value` longtext,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

With this data:

```
id, value
--------------------
'1', '__cccccccc; Myword'
'2', '__ddddddd; Myword'
'3', 'OOO; myword; anotherword'
```

And this query:

```
SELECT `mytable`.`value`
     , LENGTH(`mytable`.`value`) 'string length'
     , LENGTH(REPLACE(LOWER(`mytable`.`value`),'; myword','')) 'after replace'
     , LENGTH(`mytable`.`value`) - LENGTH(REPLACE(`mytable`.`value`,'; myword','')) 'after sub'
     , LENGTH(`mytable`.`value`) - LENGTH(REPLACE(`mytable`.`value`,'; myword',''))/8 'after divide'
  FROM mytable 
 WHERE LOWER(`mytable`.`value`) LIKE '%; myword%' 
    OR LOWER(`mytable`.`value`) LIKE '%; myword';
```

And this result:

```
# value, string length, after replace, after sub, after divide
'__cccccccc; Myword', '18', '10', '8', '16.7500'
'__ddddddd; Myword', '17', '9', '8', '15.8750'
'OOO; myword; anotherword', '24', '16', '8', '22.0000'
```

The insert statement:

```
INSERT INTO `test`.`mytable`
(`id`,
`value`)
VALUES
('1','__cccccccc; Myword'),
('2','__ddddddd; Myword'),
('3','OOO; myword; anotherword');
```

The problem is the last column result is incorrect. For example, the last column in the first record should be 8/8 which is 1. Why am I getting these results? How to correct them plz with the minimal changes?

Note: I need to convert the strings to lowercase using LOWER because replace is case sensitive and my values are case sensitive (I need to capture any occurrence of the keyword `; myword` whether it contains capital or small letters, I do not care.

**EDIT:**

The query aims to count the number of times the string `; myword` appeared. So I count the length of the field, and subtract it from the length of the field after replacing the keyword I want to count with nothing `''`. Then divide the result with the number of characters in the keyword string (8 in my case).

Comment: Please explain the logic you are trying to implement.

Comment: @Gordon Linoff see the edit plz.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The source of the problem is that REPLACE is case sensitive. So the select statement should be:

```
SELECT `mytable`.`value`
     , LENGTH(`mytable`.`value`) 'string length'
     , LENGTH(REPLACE(LOWER(`mytable`.`value`),'; myword','')) 'after replace'
     , (LENGTH(`mytable`.`value`) - LENGTH(REPLACE(LOWER(`mytable`.`value`),'; myword',''))) 'after sub'
     , (LENGTH(`mytable`.`value`) - LENGTH(REPLACE(LOWER(`mytable`.`value`),'; myword','')))/8 'after divide'
FROM mytable 
WHERE LOWER(`mytable`.`value`) LIKE '%; myword%' 
#OR LOWER(`mytable`.`value`) LIKE '%; myword';
```

You can see I added `LOWER()` inside each `REPLACE()` because REPLACE() is case sensitive and you search for keyword with small letters, so you must convert your text to small to capture every occurrence of the keyword despite the letter case.

With this query, you get this result:

```
# value, string length, after replace, after sub, after divide
'__cccccccc; Myword', '18', '10', '8', '1.0000'
'__ddddddd; Myword', '17', '9', '8', '1.0000'
'OOO; myword; anotherword', '24', '16', '8', '1.0000'
```

so the last column correctly shows the number of occurrence of the keyword in the `value` field.

Answer (score -1):

Try this function

```
delimiter $$
CREATE FUNCTION `count_str`(long_text_column TEXT, string_to_find VARCHAR(32)) RETURNS int(11)
    DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN
    RETURN ROUND((CHAR_LENGTH(long_text_column) - CHAR_LENGTH(REPLACE(long_text_column, string_to_find, ""))) / CHAR_LENGTH(string_to_find));
  END $$
delimiter ;
```

Comment: Thanks. But this is total change to my query. I do not want to change it Just solve the issue of division or understand how to fix that issue. I want minimal changes. I can not replace it with a whole new query.

Comment: just use the logic there and you need to split as per your query

Answer (score -1):

So by splitting based on your query, check out this

```
SELECT `mytable`.`value`
     , LENGTH(`mytable`.`value`) 'string length'
     , LENGTH(REPLACE(LOWER(`mytable`.`value`),'; myword','')) 'after replace'
     , LENGTH(`mytable`.`value`) - LENGTH(REPLACE(`mytable`.`value`,'; myword','')) 'after sub'
     , (LENGTH(`mytable`.`value`) - LENGTH(REPLACE(`mytable`.`value`,'; myword','')))/8 'after divide'
  FROM mytable 
 WHERE LOWER(`mytable`.`value`) LIKE '%; myword%' 
    OR LOWER(`mytable`.`value`) LIKE '%; myword';
```

Comment: can you clarify plz? I do not get what you mean by splitting? That you divided the selected fields into lines this never affects the results. However, I noticed you removed the LOWER() which I need it necessarily becasue the table data are sometimes in capital and sometimes in small letters. I need to convert them all to LOWER to avoid this case sensitivity issue.

Comment: does the above query works? and by default mysql will not check based on cases. or share create table and data samples

Comment: REPLACE is case sensitive function. I checked it now. Due to case sensitive issue, your query does not find the the keyword in the first two records and returns zero.

Comment: share create & sample data statements for table, so that can test locally

Comment: They are shared in the OP!

Comment: the query doesn't match with the data sample. share insert structure and the same query to fetch rather than x.value which is not part of the table

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. Unfortunately, someone edited my post to make this confusion. It is edited now. Plz check.

Comment: Insert statement in the sense need the insert query of data so that can test locally

Comment: You can find it now. I'm not sure if this what you want.

Comment: yeah, that's correct.. and your result set is in comma separated if you show in a tabular format it would be much better, with Expected result

Comment: I figured out the source of the problem. Will post an answer. Thanks.